# How to fix values from an array on the y-axis in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to display an array of 7 dynamic percentages on the y-axis using the property `tickPositions`, but Highcharts automatically excludes the last element of the array. How could I include this element?

My current Graph:

[image]

The result I'm looking for with highlighted addition:

[image]

Here is a sample of how I set up the y-axis,

```
yAxis: [{
            visible: false,
            labels: {
                format: " "
            },
            title: {
                text: " "
            }
        },
        {
            tickPositions: dataKickbacks.KickbackLevels.Percentage,
            endOnTick: true,
            title: {
                text: "Kickback",
                style: {
                    color: "#000000"
                }
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value}%'
            },
            style: {
                color: "#000000"
            },
            opposite: true
        }],

series: [{
        name: "Revenue",
        color: "#D8D8D8",
        type: "column",
        data: monthlyAmount,
        tooltip: {
            valuePrefix: 'CHF '
        },


    }, {
        name: "Projected Kickback",
        color: "#000000",
        type: "line",
        yAxis: 1,
        dashStyle: "line",
        shadow: true,
        data: [
            [0, initialKickbackPercentage],
            [11, projectedKickbackPercentage]
        ],
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '%'
        },

    }]
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2242o3tL/1/ works for me. Probably your tickPositions array is not valid but it is not possible to be sure if you don't include a live example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tickPositions` may not be the best approach for your needs. `tickInterval` works better for your chart.

```
yAxis: {
            tickInterval: 2.5,
            max: 15,
            min: 0,
}
```

We decided `tickInterval`, `max` and `min` values for our yAxis. So our chart will shown just like you want.

I made a working example for you which you can see here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2242o3tL/).

Comment: It works now. I had a typo mistake where I assign the array's elements to the values on the y-axis, that's why it didn't work the first time. I appreciate your help!